# Plot output "looks" different in R vs RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

Am a newb to R.   I tested some code to produce a word cloud.  The code works.   What is weird is that the output plot "looks" totally different when I run it in R vs RStudio.   Ironically in R the output looks really nice.   In RStudio it is not.

I dont think its the code and suspect it has something to do with RStudio settings.

Any suggestions?

```
cname <- file.path("", "corpus")
library (tm)
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))

library (SnowballC)

for (j in seq(docs)) {
    docs[[j]] <- gsub("/"," ",docs[[j]])
    docs[[j]] <- gsub("@"," ",docs[[j]])}

docs <- tm_map(docs,tolower)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)

library(wordcloud)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(colSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
head(v,14)
words <- names(v)
d <- data.frame(word=words, freq=v)
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq,min.freq=2)
```

Here are the two different images ... naturally there is some randomness due to the word cloud - that's not my problem - but the layouts "look" pretty different.  The R one is more flowing.   The R Studio one looks odd with words on top of each other.

[image: output using R]

[image: output using R Studio]

Comment: A simple example is always the best. You could have used an example from `?wordcloud` (e.g. the one about George Mallory). If that also produces your problem, then there's a whole lot of code clutter that can be removed from this post, and it would be reproducible. (This overlapping doesn't occur for me on Windows, RStudio 0.98.501, R 3.1.0.)

Comment: Thx - will take a look at the example from ?wordcloud.   Am using Mac, RStudio 0.98.507, R 3.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried clicking "zoom" in the RStudio preview pane? The size of the preview pane is used to set certain (default) graphical parameters, which is why the plot looks squished in comparison to the vanilla R plot. If you're outputting directly to file, you can also set size parameters in the respective commands (`pdf()`, `png()`, etc.)

Comment: thx - yes - i did play with zoom, but to me the output still looked funky no matter what i tried.   I appreciate the suggestion on setting the size - that seems helpful.   Is there a way to figure out what "size" R console is using by default?

Comment: @user3621202: Or create a plot window with `x11()` or `quartz()`, scale it to your preferred size and _then_ call `wordcloud`.

Comment: To reinforce what @jbaums said -- the best way to explicitly set your size parameters ahead of time. Look at `?Devices` to get an idea about what devices and settings are available. This is especially important if you're going to use these figures for publication: only by explicitly setting the appropriate parameters can you guarantee that you'll always get *exactly* the same output.